# Flexible number format in Java

Tags: java, number-formatting

I have a question how to write code that will convert double numbers into string using different decimal number formats based on  criteria.
For example
1) if number of integer digits < N: use number format as ####(N times).### (3 fraction digits)

2) if number of integer digits >=N: use scientific number format 0.###E0
I only come out with idea with manually counting integers digits(by dividing by 10).Then use if/else.

Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the class [`NumberFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html). You have to use condition to account for your two cases, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Although the `DecimalFormat` [JavDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) have a section "Scientific Notation" this doesn't seem to match your requirements. Perhaps you can get away with the "engineering notation" described in the JavaDoc?

If not, then the simplest way is to use two different formats like this:

```
private DecimalFormat df1 = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
private DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("0.###E0");

public String formatDouble(double d) {
    if( Math.abs(d) < 1000 )
        return df1.format(d);
    else
        return df2.format(d);
}
```